# Дорога в Питер или дорога на Питер?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно сказать: дорога в Питер или дорога на Питер?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Выбор между этими двумя возможными вариантами зависит от контекста. Имеет значение и такой субъективный момент, как намерение добраться до конечного пункта: если нужно в Тверь, при выборе маршрута может подойти "дорога **на** Москву", а если нужно в Москву и дорога к ней приводит, то на ту же дорогу логично сослаться как на "дорогу **в** Москву". Кроме того, выражение "дорога на Москву" может иметь условный и менее конкретный смысл, чем "дорога в Москву" (или даже направление на Москву): на развилке дорог может и не быть такой, которая приводит в Москву; тем не менее, это может быть единственная дорога, свернув с которой в определённом месте, можно добраться до Москвы - в таком условном наименовании может сказаться значимость конечного пункта.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы это был не Питер, а деревенька Замухрышкино, то чаще использовалось бы "В", а не "НА". "Вот это и есть дорога в Замухрышкино", – показал прохожий.

Насчет Питера... Употребляется и тот предлог, и другой. Много зависит от контекста.

*"Дорога на Питер открыта", – думал фельдмаршал фон Лееб.*

*Теперь тебе прямая дорога в Питер: поступишь в университет, будешь работать, пустишь корни..."* (чувствуете, здесь "дорога" в переносном смысле)

Answer (score 0):

> **Дорога** — *чего и к чему.* Дорога свободы. Идти дорогами побед. Упорный
>   труд - верная дорога к знанию. Война была единственной дорогой к
>   власти, Карл ХII это понимал (А.Н. Толстой).
>   (См.: Пунктуация и управление в русском языке: Справ. для работников печати. Д.Э. Розенталь. ­ М.: Книга, 1988. ­ 542 с.)
>
> Смекнув, что так и будет он **по дороге на ТЭЦ** дуть всё время в морду,
>   Шухов решил надеть тряпочку. [Александр Солженицын. Один день Ивана
>   Денисовича (1961)]
>
> ― Левий Матвей, ― охотно объяснил арестант, ― он был сборщиком
>   податей, и я с ним встретился впервые **на дороге в Виффаги**и, там, где
>   углом выходит фиговый сад, и разговорился с ним. [М. А. Булгаков.
>   Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

Как видно из приведенной выше информации, существует несколько вариантов управления. Таким образом, возможна и *дорога **на** Питер*, и *дорога **в** Питер*.
На мой взгляд, лучше звучит второй вариант.